# Snowflake SQL: Looping select statements

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to create a select statement that increments based on a variable. Ultimately I need a select statement that pulls all the comments per user. So it will look something like this:

| UserID | Comment_1 | Comment_2 | Comment_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | This rocks! | Nice! | Null |
| 234 | Hello | No | Yes |

So the max number of comments varies every time. So I have a query that pulls the max comment count. So I have a select statement similar to this:

`select userid, loop for i in range(1,max_comment) comment as comment_i end loop`

Basically I just want the column header to have comment_{INSERT COMMENT NUMBER HERE}.

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is a pivot, but in this case it would be a dynamic pivot, which is something that RDBMS's just aren't great at. I would, instead, pull all the user's comments and do the pivoting of the dynamic number of rows to columns in a more appropriate language like python pandas or excel pivot table or what-have-you. If you are dead-set on doing this in your RDBMS, then search up `Snowflake Dynamic Pivot` and you'll find examples that you can copy from. They all require multiple sql statements though.

Comment: basically you ether have tiny numbers of rows/columns, at which point you should do this in ram in your client (JNevil's point) or if you have huge numbers of columns, this will mostly be a mess, and what-ever you are doing so just to be honest, pointless or wrong. Use a ARRAY or LIST agregate function, and fake whatever value you are thinking this is providing in the client.

Answer (score 0):

achieving dynamic column names directly in a query without using stored procedures or dynamic SQL is challenging due to the fixed structure of SQL queries. However, you can achieve a similar result using the CASE statement to pivot your data

`

```
WITH NumberedComments AS (
  SELECT
    userid,
    comment,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY comment) AS comment_number
  FROM
    your_comments_table
)

SELECT
  userid,
  MAX(CASE WHEN comment_number = 1 THEN comment END) AS comment_1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN comment_number = 2 THEN comment END) AS comment_2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN comment_number = 3 THEN comment END) AS comment_3,
  -- Add more columns as needed
  MAX(CASE WHEN comment_number = max_comment THEN comment END) AS comment_max
FROM
  NumberedComments
GROUP BY
  userid;
```

`